# How to call an ASP.NET Core gRPC-Web enabled service via HTTP/2 protocol?

Tags: c#, asp.net, grpc-c#

I have an ASP.NET Core gRPC service named `Users.Api` with this `Program.cs`:

```cs
...

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder (args);

...

builder.Services.AddGrpc ();

builder.Services.AddGrpcReflection ();

WebApplication app = builder.Build ();

app.MapGrpcService<UsersService> ();

...
```

It was working fine for normal calls, but as you know, because [gRPC runs on HTTP/2 by default](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRPC#:%7E:text=It%20uses%20HTTP/2%20for%20transport), it isn't possible to do a gRPC API call via a Wapp (Web Application), for example from a Blazor WebAssembly application.

I researched and [the solution I found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/grpcweb?view=aspnetcore-8.0#:%7E:text=browser%2Dbased%20app.-,gRPC%20services%20hosted%20in%20ASP.NET%20Core%20can%20be%20configured%20to%20support%20gRPC%2DWeb%20alongside%20HTTP/2%20gRPC.,-For%20instructions%20on) was to use gRPC-Web. It uses HTTP/1 instead of HTTP/2 so browsers can call gRPC services too. So now my `Program.cs` looks like this:

```cs
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder (args);

...

builder.Services.AddGrpc ();

...

builder.Services.AddGrpcReflection ();

WebApplication app = builder.Build ();

...

app.UseGrpcWeb ();

app.MapGrpcService<UsersService> ().EnableGrpcWeb ();

...
```

Now calling gRPC services from the browsers works fine for me. But another problem appeared: When I try to interact with the gRPC-web configured service from HTTP/2 via [Postman](https://postman.com) or .NET itself, I get these errors:

```
In .NET:
Grpc.Core.RpcException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake. (InvalidResponse) HttpIOException: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake. (InvalidResponse) IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.. SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake. (InvalidResponse)")
  Source=Grpc.Net.Client
  StackTrace:
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.<GetResponseHeadersCoreAsync>d__72.MoveNext()
   at Bargeh.Identity.Api.Services.IdentityService.<Login>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Source\Bargeh\Source\Services\Bargeh.Identity.API\Services\IdentityService.cs:line 29

Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake. (InvalidResponse)

Inner Exception 2:
HttpIOException: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake.

Inner Exception 3:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..

Inner Exception 4:
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.


In Postman:
Details: 13 INTERNAL: Received RST_STREAM with code 2 triggered by internal client error: Protocol error
```

This error's reason is enabling gRPC-web, so I guess that when the web is enabled, normal HTTP/2 gRPC calls do not work well, as the server responds and reacts to every request in a proper way for HTTP/1 calls, which causes this problem for HTTP/2 gRPC clients.

Now this is my question: Is there a way to make a gRPC service respond properly to both HTTP/1 and HTTP/2 requests? Or if there's no direct solution now, is there any workaround for this, like separating ports for each protocol?

Comment: Did you add `app.UseGrpcWeb();` and `app.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>().EnableGrpcWeb();` ? How did you call your service? Post code that actually reproduces the problem

Comment: I updated the answer @PanagiotisKanavos and included the new `Program.cs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the lack of a feature called **Protocol Negotiation**. According to [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/grpcweb?view=aspnetcore-8.0#:%7E:text=browser%2Dbased%20app.-,gRPC%20services%20hosted%20in%20ASP.NET%20Core%20can%20be%20configured%20to%20support%20gRPC%2DWeb%20alongside%20HTTP/2%20gRPC.,-For%20instructions%20on:%7E:text=Enabling%20HTTP/1.1%20and%20HTTP/2%20on%20the%20same%20port%20requires%20TLS%20for%20protocol%20negotiation.%20For%20more%20information%2C%20see%20ASP.NET%20Core%20gRPC%20protocol%20negotiation.):

> Enabling HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 on the same port requires TLS for protocol negotiation.

And the solution for this problem was just to use `HTTPS` instead of `HTTP`, by configuring it in the `launchSettings.json`:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      // "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5501",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5501",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that additional configuration might be required to enable HTTPS in production, but only changing HTTP to HTTPS works for now.

You can read more about Protocol Negotiation in ASP.NET Core [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#protocol-negotiation:%7E:text=TLS%20is%20used,gRPC%20calls%20fail.).